# Compile Qt MOC and UI files in parallel on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

Is it possible to compile Qt's MOC and UI files in parallel from a Visual Studio 2010 project?

Do I have to perform a parallel build with jom on a qmake-specific make file, rather than add a custom build tool command for every UI/MOC file in the project?

**Using the /MP flag does not compile the MOC and UI files in parallel, as they use a Custom Build Tool. Only the standard compiler is invoked concurrently**

Answer (score -3):

Quoting from [Qt4 with Visual Studio: Multicore Processors](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Qt4_with_Visual_Studio#Multicore_processors):

> Multicore processors
>
> If you have a multicore processor and VS 2008 Express or higher you
>   can build programs on all cores.
>
> Visual C++ 2008’s /MP flag tells the compiler to compile files in the
>   same project in parallel. I typically get linear speedups on the
>   compile phase. The link phase is still sequential, but on most
>   projects compilation dominates.
>
> Add these line to the .pro file for release version:
>
> QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -MP[processMax] Then rebuild the
>   application.

Comment: This does not address UI/MOC file compilation; only traditional .c and .cpp files are compiled in parallel.